# Matplotbib - PercentFormatter - how to scale y axis and save plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

just two quick questions I am struggeling with.
1. How can I scale the PercentFormatter, I want to set the y axis from 0 to 100 percent. I could do it without the PercentFormatter, but there must be a way including it, right?
2. The saveplot method cuts the x labels. How can i prevent that?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['ErrorNames'], df["Frequency"], color="C0")
ax.set_xticklabels(df['ErrorNames'], rotation=90 ) ;


ax.set_ylabel('Error Frequency')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Accumulated Percentage of Frequency')
ax2.plot(df['ErrorNames'], df["cumpercentage"], color="C1", marker="D", ms=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C0")
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C1")
plt.savefig('Pareto')
plt.show()
```

[Pareto Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbZ3A.png)

Comment: Use `plt.tight_layout()` before saving the figure to prevent text from going outside the plot. I don't understand your first question, what do you want to achieve with respect to what you have right now ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It works well. The first question: The scale of the percentage adopts to the dataset (in the png you can see it ranges from 40 to 100 percent. I want to set it from 0 to 100 percent in any case. Any idea?

Comment: You can use `ax2.set_ylim([0, 100])` after calling the formatter.